# How can I print the matching String to an Integer from a 2D array in kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

My goal is to combine an array of strings `(apple,banana,orange)` and an array of ints `(4,1,3)`, then find the smallest int in that 2D array `1`, and finally print the matching string to it `banana`. I tried using `minOf` and `Arrays.deepToString` , but they didn´t work together how I intended. If someone knows a better way maybe with pairs (I don´t know a lot about that), any help is appreciated!

```
fun main(){
    var fruits = arrayOf("apple","banana","orange")
    var ratings = intArrayOf(4,1,3)
    var combined = arrayOf(fruits, ratings)

//did not work
    println(minOf(Arrays.deepToString(combined)))
}
```

Comment: Kotlin is an OO language. Don't use two parallel arrays. Use a class Fruit, with a property name (banana, apple, etc.) and a property rating (4, 1, etc.). Create a List<Fruit>. Then use the methods of List to find the fruit which has the minimal rating.

Comment: But Kotlin is *also* a functional language, and you're encouraged to even [mix functional and OO programming styles](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#is-kotlin-an-object-oriented-language-or-a-functional-one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to first combine two arrays (you could also use lists, BTW) with `zip`, then find the minimum among the pairs, and deconstruct the pair fields again:

```
val fruits = arrayOf("apple", "banana", "orange")
val ratings = arrayOf(4, 1, 3)

val (minFruit, minRating) = fruits.zip(ratings).minBy {
        (_ /* Swallow the fruit as we don't need it here */ , rating) ->
    rating
} ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find the minimum of an empty list.")

println(minFruit)
println(minRating)
```